# Unable to make batch insert into Oracle DB using MyBatis

Tags: java, spring, oracle, mybatis, ibatis

I try to make batch insert into table at Oracle database using MyBatis (integrated with Spring) .

It is a definition of method in mapper interface:

```
public void savePayments(@Param("payments") List<MassPaymentItem> payments);
```

It is a MyBatis XML mapper code:

```
<insert id="savePayments" parameterType="MassPaymentFileItem" useGeneratedKeys="false">
    INSERT INTO mass_payments
        (payment_id, file_id, msisdn, amount, status)
    <foreach collection="payments" item="payment" index="index" separator=" UNION ALL ">
        SELECT SEQ_MASS_PAYMENT.nextval, #{payment.fileId}, #{payment.msisdn}, #{payment.amount}, 0 FROM DUAL
    </foreach>
</insert>
```

When I execute this I receive MyBatisSystemException with message "nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Improper inline parameter map format.  Should be: #{propName,attr1=val1,attr2=val2}"

What is wrong? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mybatis-user/Zm9VlLpkWPc)

```
<insert id="savePayments">
   INSERT ALL
   <foreach collection="payments" item="payment">
   INTO
      mass_payments_t (payment_id, file_id, msisdn, amount)
   VALUES
      (seq_mass_payment.nextval, #{payment.fileId, javaType=Integer, jdbcType=NUMERIC}, #{payment.msisdn, javaType=String, jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{payment.amount, javaType=BigDecimal, jdbcType=NUMERIC})
   </foreach>
   SELECT * FROM dual
</insert>
```

Comment: But on 10000 records it works slower than inserting each record one by one

Answer (score 1):

I found that the first answer doesn't work for me, then i find another solution as below:

```
 <insert id="savePayments" parameterType="java.util.List" useGeneratedKeys="true">
       <selectKey resultType="java.lang.Integer" keyProperty="payment_id"
            order="BEFORE">
            SELECT SEQ_MASS_PAYMENT.nextval as payment_id FROM DUAL
        </selectKey>
        INSERT INTO mass_payments
            (payment_id, file_id, msisdn, amount, status)
            select SEQ_MASS_PAYMENT.nextval, A.* from (
        <foreach collection="payments" item="payment" index="index" separator="UNION ALL">
            SELECT 
            #{payment.fileId} as file_id,
            #{payment.msisdn} as msisdn,
            #{payment.amount} as amount,
            0 as status
            FROM DUAL
        </foreach> ) A
    </insert>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a close look at your select statement. Where one would expect column name or function, you pass parameter. You should change it to something like (notice the location of `from`:

```
<foreach collection="payments" item="payment" index="index" separator=" UNION ALL ">
        (SELECT SEQ_MASS_PAYMENT.nextval from DUAL), #{payment.fileId}, #{payment.msisdn}, #{payment.amount}, 0 
    </foreach>
```