# error while inserting java map into database using mybatis

Tags: sql, mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-generator

I am trying to insert a HashMap into database columns using mybatis. My code is as shown below

```
@Insert({ 
        "<script>",     
        "INSERT INTO msg_monitored_grp(",
            "message_id, ",
            "monitored_grp_id, ",
            "monitored_grp_name,",
            "record_creation_date) ",
            "VALUES ", 
            "<foreach collection='monitoredGroupsMap' index='key' item='value' ",
                        "separator=','>",
                    "(#{messageId}, ",
                    "#{key}, ",
                    "#{value},",
                    "#{recordCreationDate})",
            "</foreach>",
     "</script>"     
    })
    void insert(MessageMonitoredGroup monitoredGroupsMap);
```

I get the below error:

```
### The error may exist in com/db/lrc/commsurv/alert/recordstore/consumer/persistence/MessageMonitoredGroupMapper.java (best guess)
### The error may involve com.db.lrc.commsurv.alert.recordstore.consumer.persistence.MessageMonitoredGroupMapper.insert-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: INSERT INTO msg_monitored_grp( message_id,  monitored_grp_id,  monitored_grp_name, record_creation_date)  VALUES     (?,  ?,  ?, ?)  ,  (?,  ?,  ?, ?)  ,  (?,  ?,  ?, ?)  ,  (?,  ?,  ?, ?)
### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:93) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:91) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:441) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.insert(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.insert(SqlSessionTemplate.java:272) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:62) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy$PlainMethodInvoker.invoke(MapperProxy.java:152) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:85) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.insert(Unknown Source)
```

Please can you tell what is wrong here.

Comment: Oracle does not support [multi-row insert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_(SQL)#Multirow_inserts) (you should check the SQL before implementing it in MyBatis ). You can use [INSERT ALL ... SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26298458/1261766) instead. Note that it is recommended to use [batch executor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55518327/1261766) when there are many entries to insert for performance reasons.

Comment: Yep, that's not a valid syntax in Oracle. This is not an issue with MyBatis, but with the SQL you are producing.